# Slow rendering. Which GPU is a desktop process running on?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 23.10

### The question

Sometimes, applications feel like they're rendering slowly. I don't know which of the multiple GPUs is doing the work for that specific application. I would like to know which GPU is rendering a window or application. How do I find this out on a per-window or per-process basis?

### System information

My desktop is running Ubuntu 23.10 on an Intel Skull Canyon NUC. It contains a weird CPU/GPU hybrid with Intel CPU *and* AMD GPU, on the same die.

```bash
alan@nuc:~$ lscpu | grep Model\ name
Model name:                         Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8809G CPU @ 3.10GHz
```

```bash
alan@nuc:~$ lspci | grep AMD
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] 
  Polaris 22 XT [Radeon RX Vega M GH] (rev c0)
```

I also have an external GPU in a thunderbolt enclosure.

```bash
alan@nuc:~$ lspci | grep GeForce
40:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation 
  TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A] (rev a1)
```

I have three 1080p displays attached to the NVIDIA 2080 Ti. No displays are connected to the internal HDMI or DisplayPort connectors.

```bash
alan@nuc:~$ xrandr | grep "*"
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.99    59.94    50.00  
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    29.97  
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.99    59.94    50.00
```

I am running the latest version of the Nvidia driver.

```bash
alan@nuc:~$ lsmod | grep ^nvidia\ 
nvidia              56811520  920 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
alan@nuc:~$ modinfo nvidia | grep ^version
version:        535.161.07
alan@nuc:~$ dpkg -l nvidia-driver* | grep ^ii
ii  nvidia-driver-535 535.161.07-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 amd64 
  NVIDIA driver metapackage
```

*Edit*: Adding this thanks to the answer below from Alistair Buxton. Interesting that the AMD GPU is the "Default" (which I suspect isn't what I want).

So the answer is I need to use `switcheroo launch` or launch using GNOME application launcher.

```bash
alan@nuc:~$ switcherooctl list
Device: 0
  Name:        Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD®/ATI] Polaris 22 XT [Radeon RX Vega M GH]
  Default:     yes
  Environment: DRI_PRIME=pci-0000_01_00_0

Device: 1
  Name:        NVIDIA Corporation TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A]
  Default:     no
  Environment: __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only
```

### My workflow

I typically launch applications from their icon in the GNOME Shell launcher or from a shell script I manually run, which launches all my desktop applications on startup. However, there's also the option in the launcher to "Launch using Integrated Graphics Card".

For example, here's the standard Steam launcher icon menu:

[image: Steam launcher menu]

### The problem

Sometimes, I feel like applications are rendering slowly.

### Restating the question

I'd like to know how I know which GPU is in use by a process or window.

Happy to hear other opinions like:

- You're seeing things
- It's the thunderbolt which is slow

Not inclined to do any of these: :)

- Use Wayland
- Use the open source nouveau driver
- Remove the NVidia GPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `switcherooctl list` and you will see output like this for each GPU:

```
Device: 0
  Name:        NVIDIA Corporation TU104 [GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER]
  Default:     yes
  Environment: __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only
```

Note the environment section. Gnome Shell launches programs with `switcherooctl launch`, which just inserts those variables into the program's environment. So when you want to determine which GPU a program is running on, check `/proc/$pid/environ` for environment variables matching one of the devices in the list.

Edit to add: my understanding is that Gnome only uses switcheroo if you explicitly choose one of the "integrated" or "discrete" options. Otherwise it just runs the program normally. You won't see either set of variables in the environment, and absent any other config, the program will be running on whichever GPU your monitor is connected to.

But do note I don't use either Gnome or a dual GPU set up so I could be wrong about this.

You can verify that `switcheroo launch` works for a particular card by using it to launch `glxgears -info` and checking the value of `GLX_RENDERER` at the top of the output.

Comment: Thanks for that, updated the question

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is now?

Comment: Well, I think you solved it,I'll edit out the extra info. Now I know how to launch correctly, I think that's helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome 3.36, with an intel integrated video and an AMD dedicated card, I get: `switcherooctl: command not found`. Why?

Comment: It's in `switcheroo-control` package.

Comment: "Gnome Shell launches programs with `switcherooctl launch`" — But on 20.04 with Gnome 3.36, I don't have the `switcherooctl` command. So what happens on my machine? Something seems to be missing from this answer: either that `switcherooctl` is assumed to be present only under certain circumstances (Ubuntu or Gnome version, or it may get installed as a dependency of an Nvidia driver); or that if I install the `switcheroo-control` package, then that will be preferred — but not before that. I wish to know exactly what OP asks, but I still don't know what's happening on my machine.